# Proper way to refer to someone that previously held an official title, but is no longer in said title

Tags: politeness, proper-nouns, titles

I’m trying to figure out the best way to refer to someone in a resume. I once received an award from former Secretary of Defense Donald Rumsfeld when he was still the Secretary of Defense. I use this as part of my resume. I want to acknowledge that he is no longer the secretary of defense, but also want to convey that I received the award while he was actively serving. I dont want it to seem like I received some fake award from him by accidentally bumping into him at a baseball game and he gave me his left over unwanted crackerjack prize. Is there a easy way to give him a title that expresses this without actually using half a page on my resume to explain? There’s got to be a word for it, right?

Comment: The then Secretary of Defense.

Comment: How is "former secretary of Defense" bad?

Comment: @KateBunting +1 I think you should expand that into an answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to make it clear that the award was made while Mr. Rumsfeld was in post, you can say 'the then Secretary of Defense'.